# How to create animated text in FFMPEG?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I want to create video of the animated text which I enter. I want to create app like:

> Input test:xyz

and output will be the animated video of that text. I try `ffmpeg` but there is not feature like this. Any one know how to do this?

```
ffmpeg -r 12 -i "sometext" -y -an nuxified.mp4
```

Comment: It's bad practice to create a video to animate something. Very server intensive. Just use a JS solution instead.

Comment: A video _might_ be the correct solution, but it is hard to say without significantly more detail. You can animate on canvas I think, you can certainly animate in CSS and in JavaScript or via libraries like MooTools/jQuery. SVG might be worth looking at too. What kind of animation are you after? A scrolling text? Please edit your question to explain that.

Comment: I think animation of "any type" is still too broad a question for this site. Stack Overflow is really only for specific questions about programming, but it seems you're still at the design stage.